# The value of a variable in one class is recieved as null in another when called in java

Tags: java

I want to use the value of a string variable in one class into another...

But when i do so by creating an object in the calling class of the called class, i get the value as null.

I tried searching on the net and stack overflow and went through some similar answers,but the solutions to them were specific to those questions.So m asking again.

here are the 2 classes -

1st one is the class from which i want to use the variable.
class is - SelectedClass variable i want to use in another class - SelectedClass( a string)

2nd class is FEa.I want to use the value of the variable "SelectedClass" from the 1st class.

CLASS 1(SelectedClass)-

```
package com.attendance_trial.nirmik;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SelectClass extends ListActivity 
{

public String classes2[] = {"FEa","FEb","SEa","SEb"};
String SelectedClass;

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    String SelectedClass = classes2[position];
    try
    {

        Class MyClass = Class.forName("com.attendance_trial.nirmik." + SelectedClass);
        Intent myintent = new Intent(SelectClass.this,MyClass);
        startActivity(myintent);

    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnf)
    {
        cnf.printStackTrace();
    }


}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(SelectClass.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes2));
}
```

}

CLASS 2 (FEa) -

```
package com.attendance_trial.nirmik;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FEa extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{

SelectClass sc = new SelectClass();

//Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,bSend;
Button bSend;
TextView tvDisp;
String acc="";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fea);
    initialise();


}



private void initialise()//initialise all buttons etc
{

    bSend = (Button) findViewById (R.id.BtnSendMsg);
    bSend.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvDisp=(TextView) findViewById (R.id.TxtViewDisplay);

}





public void onButtonClick(View v)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Button theButton = (Button)v;
        String chk = theButton.getText().toString();
        if(chk.contentEquals("1")||chk.contentEquals("2")||chk.contentEquals("3")||chk.contentEquals("4")||chk.contentEquals("5")
                ||chk.contentEquals("6")||chk.contentEquals("7")||chk.contentEquals("8")||chk.contentEquals("9"))
        {
        acc = acc + "0" + chk;
        }
        else
        {
            acc =  acc +chk;
        }
        tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);


}//method end



@Override
public void onClick(View v2) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int retid = v2.getId();
    if(retid == R.id.BtnSendMsg ) //send button clicked
    {

        String msg = sc.SelectedClass + "2210"+ acc;
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
                startActivity(emailIntent);
    }

}
```

}//main end

Comment: your question has nothing to do with android. First form a relevant short example.

Comment: initialization error dude , the class being accessed here must be initialised

Comment: @NarendraPathai ...thats a code from an android app m making as trial! how can u say its not?

Comment: Your question statement does not reflect anything about Android and seemed vague that is why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is totally wrong.

You are not supposed to manually create objects from a class which extends an `Activity`. AKA you should never do this: `SelectClass sc = new SelectClass();`.
You have to tell the Android OS to do it for you by using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now if you want to send a String from SelectClass to FEa, you can send it with the intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_KEY, yourString);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in your second Activity, in onCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the string from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

}
```

You should check [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com) to make yourself an idea how to program in Android. Bare in mind, Android programming is not Java programming.

How to start a new Activity, from the developers site [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Comment: can u help me with the exact code...m syill learning java and android programming...m not exactly understanding what should be the message key and stuff...getting confused between the way i have created an intent before(in the above xample) and what u have said...so could u give me the exact code with commented xplaination or something? it will be helpfull...sorry for stupid questions..! still learning!

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you pass the values by using `return` ? That way you can call any function in any class and return the value to any other class.

More information on returning values or classes can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) .

Comment: This is Android, not Java!

Comment: I don't see a problem with using this since this is a java code. Also his tag is java...no need to downvote...

Comment: Again, this is NOT JAVA CODE. It doesn't matter what tag it has because the code and the logic are totally wrong. If you try to do it your way, what happens when the Android OS kills your previous activity for releasing memory? It gives you a null pointer. Before giving answers, look up the code, and if you don't fully understand what is going on, then don't say anything.